# Guava: how to customly reduce a multimap?

Tags: java, guava

Is the concept of *reduce* implemented in Guava libs? I mean I have a multimap:

```
[1] -> 1, 2, 5, 8
[2] -> 3, 6, 4
[3] -> 1, 0
```

Then I have a *multiplying function*:

```
(a, b) -> a * b
```

And I want to get the following map:

```
[1] -> 80          // 1 * 2 * 5 * 8
[2] -> 72          // 3 * 6 * 4
[3] -> 0           // 1 * 0
```

How do I do it in Guava?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there is a reduction operation in Guava. I guess you have two options.

If you're using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), just stream over the entry set, and collect the entries into a new map with `groupingBy` and `reduce`.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.reducing;

...

Map<Integer, Integer> map = 
    multimap.entries()
            .stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                reducing(1, Map.Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a * b)));
```

`groupingBy` as you can guess, will group the entries by their key values. Then we just reduce the values grouped (which are `Entry<Integer, Integer>`) by first mapping their to their values and finally by multiplying them - providing the identity value which is 1 for the multiplication.

---

If you can't use [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), you can get back a `Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>>` from your `Multimap` with `Multimaps.asMap` and use `Maps.transformValues`:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> tempMap = Multimaps.asMap(oldMap);
Map<Integer, Integer> newMap = 
    Maps.transformValues(tempMap, new Function<Collection<Integer>, Integer>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Integer apply(Collection<Integer> input) {
                //do the multiplication here
                return 0;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Used `String` key and `List<Integer>` as values.

You can also try something like

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> test = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
    test.put("a", Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3));
    test.put("b", Lists.newArrayList(4, 5, 6));

    Map<String, Integer> transformEntries = Maps.transformEntries(test, new EntryTransformer<String, List<Integer>, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer transformEntry(String key, List<Integer> values) {
            Integer a = 1;
            for (Integer value : values) {
                a = value * a;
            }
            return a;
        }
    });

    System.out.println(transformEntries);
```

Result :
{a=6, b=120}

[Maps.EntryTransformer](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.EntryTransformer.html)

Comment: That's more like what I am looking for. Will give it a try!

Comment: **Unfortunately this code is not working. Please, check yourself.**

Comment: This one works just fine, but it handles a **Map** and not a **Multimap**.

Comment: @DenisKulagin Just use `multimap.asMap()` and use `Collection<Integer>` instead of a list.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner That's a possible solution, but it includes way too many conversions and doesn't add clarity to the code (n my opinion).

Comment: @DenisKulagin `multimap.asMap()` does not convert anything. It's a lazy operation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way looks like using a stream over `entries()`, and mapping a function over it that converts the collection to a stream and runs a suitable `reduce()` function over that.

Something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> collected =
    mmap.entries().stream().collect(HashMap::new,
            (map, e) -> {
                map.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue().stream().reduce((a, b) -> (a * b)).get());
            }, HashMap::putAll);
```